# Zoom in and out on an Android LinearLayout ? Other solution?

Tags: android, android-layout

I've searched everywhere, but didnt get a answer on my question, even though it's asked fairly often!

My Question is if i can zoom a LinearLayout. I know - I can't, but is there any other way to fulfill my needs? I'm trying to do something like there is on the picture below:

Blue = any layout

Green = img

http://img140.imageshack.us/img140/2959/samplejpgx.jpg

Thanks for your help :]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understand what your needs are.
What do you mean by "zoom"? The picture you showed looks like a normal [Gallery](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html) or [GridView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html) to me...

J

Comment: thats right. I want to zoom in to and zoom out of my parentview.

Comment: ops, missclicked on Enter :P wait for more text!

Comment: Well, I've got X Imageviews inside of 1 Custom "Parent-layout". These Imageviews are listed in a 6X6 (36 ImageViews in total) style or whateverXwhatever. Locically, all pictures won't fit into the screen, that's why I want them to first shrink themselfes, and give the user the opportunity to zoom in to them to have a closer look, and l8er on, zoom out again.

Comment: mhh ok. You can set the number of columns in a grid view. I used that to switch between the normal mode of our gridview and an "overview mode" where the user can see more of the items in the grid.
So this is no real "zooming" but maybe it's enough for your needs...?

Comment: great, didnt think that was possible.